# How would I sort a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def listmerge(L1, L2):
    '''(CustomerNode, CustomerNode) -> CustomerNode
    Merge the linked lists headed by L1 and L2 into a single list with ticket_num in
    increasing order. Return the head of the merged list.
    REQ: Lists headed by L1 and L2 are sorted by ticket_num, all ticket_num    values are unique.
    '''

    current = L1
    while current.next != None:
        current = current.next
    current.next = L2
    return L1
```

An example of a customer node is like a LinkedList except its like this:

```
list1 = CustomerNode(priority, data, next = None)
```

basically i wana sort the priority. Lowest number should be the head.

So far I just did the merging.

Comment: You could iterate through the nodes, find the lowest and make it the head, remove its reference from previous Node and change it to the next of the current node, Then repeat. You could also build a list of tuples with the priority and nodes, sort by priority and then link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking, before merging your nodes, you could first sort by whichever category you want to sort by, and then do the merging using your `listmerge(L1, L2)` function.

Lets say we have these nodes:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name, data, next=None):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Note: I've replaced `priority` with `name`

Now i'm going to create a list that holds all these nodes without any sorting done:

```
nodeList = [<__main__.Node object at 0x1021e7320>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1021e7278>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1021e72b0>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1021e7240>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1021e72e8>]
```

Then I can go ahead and sort by the field I want to sort by. I'm going to assume sorting by `data`:

```
# Helper function
def getData(node):
    return node.data

sortedList = sorted(nodeList, key=getData)
```

Finally do the merging by iterating over the `sortedList` and passing each node into your `listmerge` function.

To show an example of the above results:

```
# This is the list full of unordered objects. I want to sort by the data integer values
mynodelist = [Node('a', 10), Node('b', 5), Node('c', 7), Node('d', 20), Node('e', 2)]


sortedList = sorted(mynodelist, key=getData)

for o in sortedList:
    print(o.data)

### OUTPUT ###
# 2
# 5
# 7
# 10
# 20
```

Comment: @Ali89 yup np :)